# Reworking powershell line to handle no items

Tags: powershell

Given this code block

```
    Get-Childitem -Filter '*.bak' -Recurse -exclude *baseline*  |  Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)} |  foreach-object 
{
```

i am receiving a prompt if there are no files that match the criteria.

cmdlet ForEach-Object at command pipeline position 3
Supply values for the following parameters:
Process[0]:

How would I rewrite this code to stop the script from hanging, waiting for user input?

In response to the filimonic...

```
write-host ""
write-host $DBA_BackupFileShare_NME
cd $DBA_BackupFileShare_NME\SQLServerBackup
# @( Get-Childitem -Filter '*.bak' -Recurse -exclude *baseline* ) |  
#   Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)} |  
#   ForEach-Object 
#   {
#     write-host ("{0}" -f $_.FullName)
##     [System.IO.File]::Delete($_.FullName)
#   }

[System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles('.', '*.bak',System.IO.SearchOption]::AllDirectories <# Means Recursive#>) |         Where-Object {[System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($_) -notcontains baseline'} 
ForEach-Object { Get-Item -Path $_ } |
Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)} |  
ForEach-Object 
{
 write-host ("{0}" -f $_.FullName)
 #      [System.IO.File]::Delete($_.FullName)
}
```

Comment: We cant see what your `ForEach-Object` is doing or if it is even needed. You need to also add that missing part of your code.

Comment: Given the error that you have given, it sounds like you need to provide a scriptblock for your `ForEach-Object` call. You should be getting that error regardless of if you have files found or not. Or remove the `|ForEach-Object` from the end of that line.

Comment: Santiago - the for each block work is to delete the file.

Comment: MadTech - I do not receive the error when there are files that are to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Try forcing `Get-Childitem` be an array by enclosing it into `@( )` :

```
@( Get-Childitem -Filter '*.bak' -Recurse -exclude *baseline* ) |  
   Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)} |  
   ForEach-Object {[System.IO.File]::Delete($_.FullName)}
```

Or use `EnumerateFiles`

```
[System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles('.', '*.bak', [System.IO.SearchOption]::AllDirectories <# Means Recursive#>) | 
    Where-Object {[System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($_) -notcontains 'baseline'} |
    ForEach-Object { Get-Item -Path $_ } |
    Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)} |  
    ForEach-Object {[System.IO.File]::Delete($_.FullName)}
```

And also you can run script as `powershell.exe -NonInteractive -File c:\script.ps1` which will throw error instead of waiting user input.

Comment: first code block returns this ..

cmdlet ForEach-Object at command pipeline position 2
Supply values for the following parameters:
Process[0]:

Comment: second block returns same results, but parameter 4

Comment: I think you missing `{` in | `ForEach-Object {` somewhere